# How to "tee" /dev/video in Linux?

Tags: linux, video, input-devices

How can I "tee" the output of a /dev/videox device, so that the live video stream can be consumed by two programs at the same time?

I want to send live video from /dev/video1:input=1:norm=NTSC to two programs at once (mplayer and mencoder), in order to get a non-laggy live view at the same time mencoder is recording.

I know how to take the just-encoded output from mencoder and play it, but that introduces a delay of several frames (too much). I'm told VLC can do this, but also not without significant lag.

The best I can do now is to have mplayer play it to the screen, and at time same time use "avconv -f x11grab" to grab the video off the display and encode it. That works (it doesn't add latency) but grabbing video off the display is slow - I end up with around 10 fps instead of 30.

There must be some straightforward way to "tee" /dev/video1 into two virtual devices, so both mplayer and mencoder can read them at the same time (without one of them complaining that the device is "busy").

What is that way?

Comment: FWIW, I gave up on this - nobody seems to know how.

It's quite easy to do in Python tho - so I did it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but do it in a single program: `GStreamer` ([try `gst-launch`](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+10%3a+GStreamer+tools)). It does for video streams what `bash` does for input/output pipes.

GStreamer's [camerabin2](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/2012.5/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-0.10/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-camerabin2.html) plugin can do what you need without a lag: both play the stream and record it. Though currently it can be used only from a client code, not from `gst-launch`.

GStreamer does have a [`tee` filter](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html) if you need to do something more complex, like encoding and sending the video stream over, say, RTP network protocol.